# Show table status in a subquery?

Tags: mysql

Is this not supposed to work in MySQL?

```
select * from (show table status like '%fubar%') as t1;
```

or even

```
select name, rows from (show table status like '%fubar%') as t1 where rows>0;
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show table status like '%fubar%') as t1' at line 1

Can `show table foo like '%something%'` or `show tables like '%something%'` not be used in a subquery in this way? How else could you select from all tables matching a certain pattern?

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT table_name as name, table_rows as rows FROM information_schema.tables as t1
WHERE table_rows > 0
```

Here is an alternate way of retrieving the information you are looking for.